# Как нарисовать на канвасе кольцо с альфа-градиентом?

Tags: customview, android, canvas

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как нарисовать на канвасе кольцо, у которого постепенно увеличивается прозрачность? Нужен аналог бесконечного прогресс бара, но без использования картинок.

[image]

Comment: если не секрет зачем? по идеи можно  просто рисовать окружность по формуле в цикле меня прозрачность цвета

Comment: потому, что это надо будет еще вертеть :)

Comment: если вопрос только в том чтобы вертеть так это совсем не вопрос )) у гугла в примерах анимации это первый пример

Comment: да не все так просто, я не стал расписывать полньстью всю задачу, ибо остальное я знаю как сделать. Осталось нарисовать только вот такую штуку

Answer (score 1):

Отвечая на вопрос: рисуете в onDraw(Canvas) фигуру (в xml тег shape) с типом ring.
[Shapes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

Далее, попиксельно меняете прозрачность фигуры. Думаю уже есть готовые методы, поищите, чтобы не изобретать свое. Возможно еще может помочь AlphaAnimation вместе с ObjectAnimator. И добавлю, что рисование на канве - не самая лучшая идея. Это довольно медленно, к тому же нужно уметь с ней работать.

НО есть ощущение, что вашу задачу решит обычный ProgressDialog с шагом прогресса, а в качестве картинки ему задайте то, что у Вас в вопросе.

Пробуйте )

Comment: не выдейт просто так сделать, но я сделал уже другую реализцию